# How to pass parameter from express to normal const variable?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, parameters, parameter-passing

I have an `express` POST router which sends data over to my other NodeJS script.

For example, I send over `username, password`

This is my script I want to send these parameters to

```
const options = {
  cookiesPath: './cookies.json',

  username: {I want to send username here},
  password: {I want to send password here},
  userslist: null,
  dryrun: false,
}
```

This `options` file is called again later in the code inside a different `async` function by

```
const doWork = async (users = []) => {
    usersToBeUsed = users;
    const instauto = await Example(browser, options);
}
```

How can I catch these parameters in my `const options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you're sending a form with two inputs named username and password and its values. Your route will look like this:

```
router.post("/my/path", controller.myFunction);
```

Then your function should look something like this:

```
exports.myFunction = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body); //See how your data looks like
  const options = {
    cookiesPath: './cookies.json',
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password,
    userslist: null,
    dryrun: false,
  };
  //do something with the data and send the response, render, etc...
};
```